# Xamarin form: new kind of error GetAppearedOrDisappearedTask

Tags: xamarin.forms

With the last update of `Xamarin.Forms` ver. 2.3.4.224 same new kind of errors appeared. For example this error

> NavigationRenderer.GetAppearedOrDisappearedTask (Xamarin.Forms.Page page)

[image: GetAppearedOrDisappearedTask]

What can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference at the moment this is a Xamarin bug: more info on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38731).